# Is there a way to solve for x an equation of the form: $ax^2 = b^x$ ( say, with a, b positive integers)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The symbolab math solver has no solution to give for the equation :

$3x^2 = 5^x$ .

Under which conditions, ( if there is any) an equation of this form could be solvable?

Trying to solve this equation, I arrived at :

$\log_5|x| = x - \log_53 $,

Which seems hopeless.

Comment: You might be interested in the product-log function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) solution.  First, get it in form $ae^a = b$.
$$
3x^2 = 5^x
$$
we want a solution with $x$ real.  So
$$
3x^2 5^{-x} = 1\\
3x^2 e^{-x\log 5} = 1\\
$$
take square root, both sides are positive, so choose the $\pm$ to make $\pm x \ge 0$.
$$
\pm\sqrt{3} x \exp\left(\frac{-x\log 5}{2}\right) = 1\\
-\frac{x\log5}{2} \exp\left(\frac{-x\log 5}{2}\right) = \mp\frac{\log5}{2\sqrt3}
$$
use the definition of $W$, namely $ae^a=b\;\Longleftrightarrow\;a = W(b)$
$$
-\frac{x\log5}{2} = W\left(\mp\frac{\log5}{2\sqrt3}\right)\\
x = -\frac{2}{\log5}W\left(\mp\frac{\log5}{2\sqrt3}\right)
$$
This agrees with Sonnhard's answers.  The one with $-$ inside the $W$ is not real, however.

Comment: @GEdgar.Thanks for this detailed solution. I had never heard about this useful W function.

Answer (score 1):

It is $$x_1-2\,{\frac {{\rm W} \left(-1/6\,\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 5 \right) \right)
}{\ln  \left( 5 \right) }}
$$
or
$$x_2=-2\,{\frac {{\rm W} \left(1/6\,\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 5 \right) \right)
}{\ln  \left( 5 \right) }}
$$

Comment: Which branch of the Lambert W function are you assuming here?

Comment: The only real solution is $x_2$ for the principal branch.  For complex solutions you can use any branch.